# JBoss, GWT app and form based auth timeout issue

Tags: gwt, jboss, session-timeout, form-authentication, j-security-check

Our setup is a JBOSS wildfly application server with a GWT application deployed. We use form based auth, and for testing the timeout I have changed session-timeout in web.xml to 1 minute.

So, I login to the application and wait for >1 minute and then perform an action that I know will trigger a RPC invocation, which will fail because the session has expired. We catch the exception and perform a page reload to trigger the login form to appear.

If I login immediately after the login form appears (or within 1 minute), I am successfully logged back in to the application. This pattern, I can continue for as long as I care for.

But if I wait 3-5 minutes (well after the session timeout value) after the login form appears, the browser is redirected to `http://ourdomain/myapp/j_security_check` (and the statuscode is 200 when I look in the firefox developer/network tool). When I check the HTTP response, there is no Location attribute (which there is normally).

Can anyone tell me why this is? Does the j_security_check servlet has a timeout, where the user needs to login x minutes after the login form is presented and is it connected to the session-timeout in web.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form based authentication uses a session and stores the "URL that was originally requested" in that session. When you sign in, the URL is read from the session and used as the target of the redirect. So if you wait "too long" after the login form is displayed such that the session has timed out, you've just lost that data and the server does not know where to redirect you to.

Anyway, this is a flaw in how form based authentication is defined in the Servlets spec (and I had never thought about it, so thanks for asking the question ;-) ) in that, even if not using the same configuration as sessions (the spec does not mandate the use of sessions for that, though most –if not all– containers just use sessions), the spec says (emphasis mine):

> The login form associated with the security constraint is sent to the client and the
>   URL path and HTTP protocol method triggering the authentication is **stored by
>   the container.**
>   […]
>   If authentication succeeds, the client is redirected to the resource using the store
>   URL path.
>   […]
>   If the form based login is invoked because of an HTTP request, the original request
>   parameters must be preserved **by the container** for use if, on successful
>   authentication, it redirects the call to the requested resource.

(note: the container might store the info in a cookie without expiration, then that would just work, while still following the spec; are container developers just too lazy to do it right after all these years? or do they just think it's not worth fixing?)

Comment: Thank you for your answer :) It does seem odd to me, that this scenario is not handled in a better way.